# Why is this reduce based array sum not working (JS)?

Tags: javascript

I've checked the answer to a similar question, but it doesn't quite solve it.

```js
let qties = [
  [12, 45, 56, "", 45, "", "", ""]
]
const incomingBulkQty = qties[0].reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
console.log('Result: ' + incomingBulkQty)
```

**Result should be** `158`

I have to identify the elements' indexes as such, given my real world context.

Comment: The question is not clear, can you please clarify what you want to do and what is the expected result

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @brk! I did put the expected result from the sum of ```incomingSizes```.

Comment: Why is the result meant to be `158`? If you're trying to sum the numbers then the answer should be `316`, shouldn't it? What is the purpose of that `map`? What do you mean by "I have to identify the elements' indexes? How do they apply to the question?

Comment: You're right, @Andy! I've corrected the question above. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Or trying to add only some elements like `12,45,56,45` will be `158`

Comment: this is a way to sum array  numArray.forEach(a => { if (typeof a === 'number') {sum+a;}});  .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you add an empty string, the number is converted to a string and you're just doing subsequent string concatenation.

Here we can just wrap in `Number` since the string is always an empty string. Otherwise we'd also have to do an `isNaN` check.

```js
let qties = [
  [12, 45, 56, "", 45, "", "", ""]
]
const incomingBulkQty = qties[0].reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + Number(a), 0);
console.log('Result: ' + incomingBulkQty)
```

Comment: One would rather filter out the non-numerical values.

Comment: @xehpuk it's perfectly valid to do that, but I wouldn't do that because all that does is create another temporary array and loop through (almost \*) everything again.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `incomingSizes` is an array and contains empty space so inside reduce callback function you are adding a number with string which will create a data type string. Any further addition will concate the string instead of number addition

```js
let incoming = [
  [12, 45, 56, "", 45, "", "", "", null, 158]
]

const osCol = 0;
const incomingSizes = incoming.map(e => [e[osCol], e[osCol + 1], e[osCol + 2], e[osCol + 3], e[osCol + 4], e[osCol + 5], e[osCol + 6], e[osCol + 7]])[0];
const incomingBulkQty = incomingSizes.reduce((partialSum, a) => {
  if (parseInt(a, 10)) {
    partialSum += a
  }
  return partialSum;
}, 0);
console.log('Result: ' + incomingBulkQty)
```

Comment: What is the point of the `osCol` stuff?

Comment: @Samathingamajig this was in my original question.